# Is $X$ one dimensional

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

If $X $ is an inner product space and if there exists $x \in  X $ s.t. $\{x\}^{\perp}=0$. Is $X$ one dimensional?

---

The way I have written out this question a bit wrong because it was in my exam so I don't know word for word. I thought that $\{x\}^{\perp}=0$ then this means by theorem that $<x> =\{ ax : a\in \mathbb R \}$ is dense in $X$. So $X= \bar{<  x >}$. So it  is one dim?

Comment: Are you assuming $X=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: the second part of your statement has nothing to do with $X$. you are saying if $X=\mathbb{R}$ and blah, then is $X$ 1-D. Well, since $X=\mathbb{R}$, it is certainly 1D

Comment: I think maybe it was written as X being an inner product space maybe? Would that make more sense?

Comment: I don't think it would make sense for x to be in X right? because it is supposed to be a vector?

Comment: The theorem you are using is true for Hilbert spaces. In general, it isn't true (totality of a set $A$ is equivalent to $A^\perp=\{0\}$ on Hilbert spaces).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x=0$. Then, it is easy to show that $X=\{0\}$. Therefore $\mathrm{dim}X=0$.

Suppose $x\neq 0$. Assume WLG that $\|x\|=1$. Then, there is at least one vector $u\in X$, $u\neq x$. Take $u^\prime=u-\langle u,x\rangle x$. It is easy to show that $0=\langle u^\prime,x\rangle$. Thus, $u^\prime=0$. Therefore $u-\langle u,x\rangle x=0$. That is $u\in\mathrm{span}\{x\}$. This means $X=\mathrm{span}\{x\}$, and therefor $\mathrm{dim}X=1$.

Comment: What does the element $u-\langle u,x\rangle x$ represent?